# Create text output of multiple arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three arrays that looks like this:

```
arr1 = ["Chrysler", "blue", "red"]
arr2 = ["Hyundai", "green", "black"]
arr3 = ["Ford", "black", "red"]
```

and I want to output them (to a webpage) like this:

```
black Ford Hyundai
blue Chrysler
green Hyundai
red Chrysler Ford
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I see the pattern between the arrays and the output. You can of course get the text from each array item. Such as: `arr[2] + " " + arr3[0] + " " + arr2[0] => "black Ford Hyundai"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr1 = ["Chrysler", "blue", "red"];
var arr2 = ["Hyundai", "green", "black"];
var arr3 = ["Ford", "black", "red"];
var arrays = [ arr1, arr2, arr3 ];

function Car(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.colors = new Set();
}

var cars = {};
var colors = new Set();

for (var idx = 0; idx < arrays.length; idx++) {
    var carData = arrays[idx];
    if (!cars[carData[0]]) {
        var model = new Car(carData[0]);
        for (var idx2 = 1; idx2 < carData.length; idx2++) {
            var color = carData[idx2];
            model.colors.add(color);
            colors.add(color);
        }
        cars[model.name] = model;
    }
}

for (let color of colors) {
    var output = color;
    for(var name in cars) {
        if (cars.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            var car = cars[name];
            if (car.colors.has(color)) {
                output += " "+car.name;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object for the colors and assign the brands to it. later for the output order colors and brand and return the values.

```js
var arr1 = ["Chrysler", "blue", "red"],
    arr2 = ["Hyundai", "green", "black"],
    arr3 = ["Ford", "black", "red"],
    colors = {};

[arr1, arr2, arr3].forEach(function (a) {
    var m = a.shift();
    a.forEach(function (b) {
        colors[b] = colors[b] || [];
        colors[b].push(m)
    });
});

Object.keys(colors).sort().forEach(function (c) {
    console.log(c + ' ' + colors[c].sort().join(' '));
});
```